# Click event triggers when press Enter key on Jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick, enter

I am in a big problem. In my website, I am using a search box. When `click/enter` press on the search result will redirect to the specific page. I also given a `hide()` of search results when click on other parts of window. The problem is, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key over a result, it execute the click function and remove the search output window content. I only need to clear the search result on mouse click.

This is my click event code

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
if (!$(e.target).is('#search_result')) {
        $("#search_result").hide();
    $("#search_result").html("");

    }

});
```

and my enter event is

```
function TriggerSearch(e) {
    var search_string = $("#search").val();
    e = e || window.event;
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) {
        keycode = e.which ? window.event.which : window.event.keyCode;
    }
    var key = e.which;
    switch (key) {
    case 38:
        break;
    case 40:
        break;
    case 13:
        search_product();
    break;
    default:
        default function();
    }
}
```

The call to TriggerSearch is

```
$("#search").keyup(TriggerSearch);
```

These 3 parts contain the work flow. When press an <kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than go to the `search_product()` function, it execute the click event. It did not enter to the `search_product()` function. As per my knowledge, when a `click` event occur on `#search`, then it will go to the `TriggerSearch()` function and if it is 13, then execute the `search_product()` function. I can't understand why this not happening.

How can I prevent to execute the click event on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key?

Comment: where is the call to `TriggerSearch(e)` ?

Comment: I edited the question. Now the calling is there

Comment: Post the html markup. What is the structure of search_result?

Comment: how pressing `enter` key triggers `click` if you are not doing that intentionally? (at least I don't see this in the given code)

Comment: when `click` event occurs on #search, it won't execute `TriggerSearch`, only on `keyup`, which means releasing a keyboard key, not a mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to not use a global click handler. Instead bind it to the search field `$('#searchField').click()`. Second, you might like to use blur and focus events on the search box to trigger the hiding of content.

A live demo would help narrow down what you're trying to achieve also.

Answer (score 3):

`preventdefault()` should do the trick (as you are passing the standard event object to `TriggerSearch` via the `keyup` event). **Update: You have to use the `keypress`event instead of `keyup` as it is the one that triggers a form submit.**

```
case 13:
        e.preventDefault();
        search_product();
```

*If not, please post the rest of the code :)*

### Update:

The problem is that the default form submission is triggered on keypress, not keyup. I changed it to use `keypress` instead and the preventDefault (capital D, sorry) now works:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qLK94/1/

```
function search_product() {
    alert("search_product()");
}

function TriggerSearch(e) {
    var search_string = $("#search").val();
    e = e || window.event;
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) {
        keycode = e.which ? window.event.which : window.event.keyCode;
    }
    var key = e.which;
    switch (key) {
        case 38:
            break;
        case 40:
            break;
        case 13:
            e.preventDefault();
            search_product();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
$("#search").keypress(TriggerSearch);
```

To test, comment out `e.preventDefault();` in the JSFiddle and the page will then try to submit on Enter.

### Update (submit button  not needed)

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qLK94/2/

Based on comments below I should clarify that the submit action I mentioned does not relate to the submit button, but the form. This example has no submit, but does what is wanted.

*Note: I had to remove your `default function()` as it gave an error.*
   What is that supposed to do?

Comment: thank you for the reply...but still it works the same as before.. :(

Comment: It's `preventDefault` with a capital D.

Comment: but it would prevent the `keyup` event, not `click`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @anthony Grist, Still no change :(

Comment: The problem is `keypress` triggers the submit, not `keyup`. Example added.

Comment: @ TrueBlueAussie, Thank you for the try. But I dont hav a submit button. I am just using a Button and working by using jquery

Comment: Please update the JSFiddle to match your actual form. My psychic abilities *are not what they will be* :)

Comment: Note: You do not need a submit button. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qLK94/2/